# Bold Setting on Coffee Maker

Tags: equipment, coffee

I have a 12-cup programmable coffee maker (of the now - defunct Sears variety) and used the "bold" setting to brew a stronger coffee for a specific recipe. But, it now seems stuck on bold. How do I get it back to regular? I read the manual and have tried unplugging it, which reset everything but that. I then tried selecting bold for my next pot to see if that would turn it off. I have now brewed 5 pots of strong coffee when I only needed one pot for my recipe.

Comment: put less coffee in the machine ?

Comment: Is it possible that the button is mechanically stuck?

Answer (score 3):

All other things being equal (water, bean, grind, filter...) the "mechanical" effect of a bold setting is to constrict the flow rate so that the water is perculating with the coffee for a longer period, thus rendering a 'stronger' (or more bold) flavor. (see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/20202/6279)

If you feel like your coffee maker is 'stuck on bold' I would give the machine a **[thorough cleaning](https://www.wikihow.com/Clean-a-Coffee-Maker)** as the flow control is probably 'stuck'. I don't know that I would say clean after every use (if you use it daily...) but you are probably long overdue for a deep cleaning .